# Azure Jfrog Integration - Yaml pipeline limit number of searches

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, artifactory, jfrog-cli

I want to limit my search to only 1 last updated file how can I add this to my code ? I tried to add limit(1) after curly, square bracket but it didn't work. Does anyone know how to apply this to my code ?

```
ArtifactoryGenericDownload@3
    inputs:
      connection: "JFROG"
      specSource: "taskConfiguration"
      fileSpec: |
        {
            "files": [
                {
                    "target": "./$(Pipeline.Workspace)/de-cf-dnalib",
                    "aql": {
                        "items.find":{
                            "repo":"python",
                            "$and":[
                                {
                                    "$and": [
                                        { "name": { "$match": "*.whl" } },
                                        { "modified": { "$last": "10d" } }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "$and": [
                                        { "name": { "$nmatch": "*dev*" } }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
      failNoOp: true
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [this documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Using+File+Specs) `limit` should be adjacent to `aql` field. Can you try this?

```
{
  "files": [
    {
      "target": "./$(Pipeline.Workspace)/de-cf-dnalib",
      "aql": {
        "items.find": {
          "repo": "python",
          "$and": [
            {
              "$and": [
                {
                  "name": {
                    "$match": "*.whl"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "modified": {
                    "$last": "10d"
                  }
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "$and": [
                {
                  "name": {
                    "$nmatch": "*dev*"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "limit": 1
    }
  ]
}
```